# Second parameter in rtrim function

Tags: php

I use `rtim()` function to remove null char from end of string.

Ex:

```
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0");
```

I saw example with `rtrim($toBeTrimed , "\0\4")`. I know that `"\0"` is null char but I don't know what mean `"\0\4"`.

My question is, what mean `"\4"` or `"\0\4"`?

Comment: http://php.net/string - look for *Octal*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP inside a double-quoted string, this is the Octal number of the character (C characters; see ASCII):

> `\[0-7]{1,3}` - the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation

In your case of `"\0\4"` that are two characters: Character octal 0 and octal 4.

- `\0` - NUL character
- `\4` - EOT (End Of Transmission) character

In this case it means that `rtrim` will remove the NUL and EOT character(s) from the right of the string (if there are any of those).

See as well:

- http://php.net/string#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: thank, i understand now what "\4" mean. Is good to use in that example?

Comment: @Alexandru: It is out of my knowledge if it is good to use in that example. Take care that you do not cut-away the wrong characters because this can destroy things.